# Localization project in ASP.net MVC4 with Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a project in MVC4 with Razor and I want it to be multilingual, I have a dropdownlist with several languages and I need the page to change when the user select an option in the dropdonlist, example:

- default option "en" - default url "/myproject.com"
- option "es" - url "/myproject.com/es/miproyecto"
- option "it" - url "/myproject.com/it/mioprogetto"

I know I must use routes and resources, but how?

Comment: I don't recommend using URIs to localise a website, instead use the `Accept-Language` HTTP header to choose the language, or use a cookie to override it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here Scott Hanselman http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GlobalizationInternationalizationAndLocalizationInASPNETMVC3JavaScriptAndJQueryPart1.aspx explaining it very well.

But be careful on multilingual websites you also have to test your JavaScript for the other languages.

I would use only one URL and use Resource Strings in your project for the different languages. Because this is better/easier for search engines like Google to find your Information and show them for one URL.

Comment: thank you for your answer but what I need actually is to use both approaches, I need (because of SEO things) different urls according to the selected language, but at the same time I want to use one parametrized view for all languages, I think routes and resources are the way, but I don't know exactly how.